How to separate notifications from software in different workspaces?
I'm an English learner, so please forgive any mistakes in my grammar. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop and I'm having an issue with my workspaces.
I have 4 workspaces set up, with the first one being my main workspace and the third one designated for social media applications. I've enabled the option to "Include applications from the current workspace only." However, when I receive a new message from applications like Telegram on the third workspace, they still appear in the first workspace when I use Alt + Tab. This behavior is quite annoying and persists until I manually switch to the third workspace.
Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how I can ensure that applications stay within their designated workspaces? I've already checked the relevant settings, but I haven't been able to find a solution.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
